# Introduction of the new tag: "TTS"

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I am somehow concerned about missing tags in Software Engineering, on Stackoverflow, several terms can be found quite easily, whilst they are missing on Software Engineering, e.g. [TTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text-to-speech).

Is it possible that someone can add them?

Comment: Tags are added organically, as a question is created that requires the tag. If the asker of the question can't add it, it can be added later. Are there one or more questions where adding this tag would add value?

Comment: @ThomasOwens yes indeed, I realized, that there are quite some questions concerning this topic around, but searching for them is not easy, e.g. some write TTS, the others write text to speech, whilst some write text-to-speech, and others use the term speech engine only, e.g. my last question is about TTS: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401202/which-tts-engine-can-i-use-that-is-foss

Comment: Perhaps you can identify a few on-topic questions where adding the tag can add value. That question has been flagged and subsequently deleted for being off-topic.

Comment: I still don't get the point why it is off-topic? Could you explain it, because as I read the Community rules, it stands: "Software development methods" are on-topic. Which I was asking for, was about an method to implement TTS on a website with FOSS.

Comment: @ThomasOwens https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101243/any-ideas-for-a-good-way-to-get-html-text-to-speech seems pretty much the same question that I asked, and should also be tagged with TTS

Comment: These are two different questions. If, after reading the [Help Center's definition about what makes a good, on-topic question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you aren't clear why both of the questions you've identified are off-topic, you should open a new question here on Meta. If you believe that a new tag is necessary, please identify a few good, on-topic questions where the tag would add value - a tag can't be created without being attached to an open, undeleted question.

Comment: I think we shouldn't discuss in the comment section, as you might know, that is also not very welcomed here. On the other hand, I think I find it a big problem that questioners are denied the questions. Software engineering should be exactly what Stack Overflow is for problems, a page that allows developers to ask questions, which are about Software Engineering. I couldn't come up with an logical explanation for deleting my question. If this are the rules, then the rules are not logical.

Comment: @ErdincAy: the rule not to ask for 3rd party resources like tools, libraries or papers sounds pretty clear to me (for TTS tools/libs, you can ask on softwarerecs.SE instead). And the discussion about why the scope of this site is today as it is (regardless if you and me like it or not), has a long standing history, see, for example [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7539/revisiting-what-is-on-topic-with-respect-to-new-sites-open-source-law-and-so)

Comment: @DocBrown First of all thanks for your response. Noone here ever mentioned Software-Recommendations as an sub-site of SE. Second, I would like to ask, if .Net (C#) and Java are not a third-party resource or tool, or library? Who decides, what is a tool that shall not be asked for? In my opinion everything, that you didn't wrote yourself, including the compiler, programming language is a tool, library or resource from third-party. As I said earlier, I do not see any logic here, but for future I will use softwarerecs for this kind of questions.

Comment: @ErdincAy: questions are not automatically off-topic just because a 3rd party resource like a specific programming is **involved**, that is not what the scope definition in the help center tells. But a question like "should I use Java or C# for this" is likely to be closed, that would require an opinionated recommendation. And I agree to Thomas Owens: if you are still confused why a specific question is closed, or another one is not, ask a new question here on meta, give a reference to the question, then we can give you an explanation.

Comment: @DocBrown I probably won't do, because I will just use segregation of concerns: 1. implementation issues on SO, 2. implementation methods on SE, 3. software-related questions on SR, and hope not to violate the respective policies. Wish you well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making a search with the keywords *"text to speech is:question"* gave me 12 results, of which I think only 3 would be candidates for a TTS tag. That is way too few for justifying a tag on its own - everyone can find those relevant questions quickly without a special tag.

For curiosity, I tried the same search on Stackoverflow: it gave me 7465 results, whilst a search for the tag "[text-to-speech]" reduced this to 2859 results, so here the category narrows the results of such searches significantly.

Stackoverflow has currently more than 18 million questions, SE.SE however less than 60 thousands, so it is quite natural we require here way fewer tags for categorization than Stackoverflow.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your efforts, I had the same search results, but I assumed that the opposite is true, because of the lack of tags, the results are so small. I still assume, that due to missing tags, a lot of those questions, that might also be TTS are not findable due to missing tags. Just for a second, think of the situation of wrongly written words e.g. text to spech or text to speach, which can happen.